# How to Prevent Cursor From Reverting to Far Left of Screen after Newlines in Ncurses?

Tags: ncurses

Using the function mvprintw(rowOffset, colOffset, textToPrint) from Ncurses, when I print a newline character, if colOffset is anything other than 0, I get a rectangle that looks like this:

```
   xxxxxxxx
x      x
xxxxxxxx
```

when I want the rest of the rectangle to align with the top

for

```
#include <ncurses.h>

    void main()
    {
        initscr();
        mvprintw(7,3,"xxxxxxxx\nx      x\nxxxxxxxx\n");
        refresh();
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a *window*, which starts at *`7,3`*, and writes to the window will wrap on newline to column-offset 3, e.g.,

```
#include <ncurses.h>

void main()
{
    WINDOW *w;
    initscr();
    w = newwin(10,20, 7, 3);
    wprintw(w, "xxxxxxxx\nx      x\nxxxxxxxx\n");
    wrefresh(w);
    wgetch(w);
}
```

This creates a 10-line window.  You could create a larger one, by taking into account the actual screen-size (e.g., [**`LINES`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_variables.3x.html#h3-LINES)).

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks. I did have to change WINDOW w to WINDOWS * w, however, for it to compile.